# NgModule and FormModule importing on every module?

Tags: forms, angular, module

So I'm using RC5, and when embracing things seems to go pretty decently for now I ran into an issue which I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or is working as intended;

Before it was possible to make form directives etc. globally available. Nowadays we started using NgModule. It seems though that I can't use FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule globally, either in AppModule nor in a SharedModule. I need to import it in every single module I create.

Is this as intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this NgModule doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) it is as intended,

- so if you are using multiple NgModule heirarchy in your app, you will need to create a **`SharedModule`** and **import/export** all the global `Modules/Components/Directives/Pipes` in it.
- then import this module in every Module that you want to share it with.

---

*You can read [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) for more clarification.*

Answer (score 4):

You should add `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to your `SharedModule` exports, then you need to import your `SharedModule` into your other modules. That way, you will be able to use desired directives globally.

Comment: Is this true for ReactiveFormsModule in Angular 7? The [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-injecting-the-formbuilder-service) state that `The FormBuilder service is an injectable provider that is provided with the reactive forms module`. So wont this duplicate that service?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the class with the directives which you need, an example of this is:

1. Create a file **ngforms.module.ts** (can be on the root app)
2. Write this:

> ```
> import { NgModule }                         from '@angular/core';
> import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports:[
>     FormsModule,
>     ReactiveFormsModule,
>   ],
>   exports:[
>     FormsModule,
>     ReactiveFormsModule,
>   ]
> })
> export class NgFormModule {}
> ```

3. In every module or submodule for your app you have to import and call it

> ```
> import { NgFormModule } from './ngform.module';
> imports: [
>     //Angular material
>     BrowserAnimationsModule,
>     //Angular (forms)
>     NgFormModule
>   ],
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule globally, in my `app.module.ts` like this:

```
 imports: [ // module dependencies
         BrowserModule, routing,
         FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule,...
     ]
```

Comment: And that works for you in sub modules? Since when I try to do it like that it starts complaining whenever it encounters [formGroup]

Comment: well,  you have to `import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';` anyway

Comment: Hi Xavi, i found out that your solution doesn't work for sub modules, however when you have a "shared module" you can export Formsmodule and ReactiveFormsModule and it does work.